# How to make a direct link for opening iframe link

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am stuck creating a WordPress menu link for an iframe page item link- this is what we use opening a link in an iframe

`<a href="https://..." target="iframe-id">Open in iFrame</a>`

I want to give this link to one of my WordPress menu link. How do I do it? Please guide. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(document).on('click','[target="iframe-id"]',function(){
    $("#load-iframe").attr('src', $(this).attr('href')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
iframe{
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.lipsum.com/" target="iframe-id">Open in iFrame</a>

<!-- Put This Somewhere on the page -->
<iframe id="load-iframe" src="">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for updating... I am a nubee, just lost in where to put this jquery? how to add this in functions.php using functions and add_action scripts? Thanks for your support.